# Is there anything like Lisp's SLIME for Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, lisp, slime

I know about the Django console and it's useful to an extent but it would be really nice to be able to edit your code with the console open, lime SLIME in Emacs. Is there anything that facilitates this for Django or, failing that, at least Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but Workzeug provides a interactive debugging tool, which can be used like that. Just do a `assert False` and you can use the CLI as demonstrated in this screencast: http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/sep/12/screencast-django-command-extensions/

Answer (score 2):

[IDLE](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html)

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
django-admin.py shell
```

in your project should give you what you want. If you have IPython installed, you also get all of the fancy highlighting and completion features it offers too.

Comment: Or install django-command-extensions and resotr to `shell_plus`